# Toggle image(flag's) in language panel

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a language panel in which I have one `image` (`main-image`) that show's when the page is loaded. I also have three additional `image's` which are hidden when the page loads.

The question is **how to toggle main image when one of the additional `image's` is clicked**. I need to toggle main-image  with the `image` which is clicked.

Here is [**Codepen**](https://codepen.io/DuudeXX8/pen/ZRVaOB?editors=1010)

**My first try**

```
let menuBtn = document.getElementById("menu-btn");
menuBtn.addEventListener("click", ()=>{
    let mainBtnImg = document.getElementById("main-btn-img");
    let otherThreeImg = document.querySelectorAll(".menu-img");
    for(let i = 0;i< otherThreeImg.length; i++){
        mainBtnImg.src = otherThreeImg[this].src;
    }
})
```

**Second try**

changed this part only

```
mainBtnImg.src = this.otherThreeImg;
```

**Downvoters please comment first**

```js
$(document).on('click', function (e) {
    if ($(e.target).closest(".menu-btn").length === 0) {
        $('.menu-nav').removeClass('menu-nav--open');
    }
});

$('.menu-btn').on('click', function(e){
 e.preventDefault();
 $(this).toggleClass('menu-btn--open');
 $('.menu-nav').toggleClass('menu-nav--open');
});
```

```css
body, html {
  margin: 0;
}

.section {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background: linear-gradient(#55efc4, #ffeaa7);
  position: relative;
}

.menu-btn__wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  right: 20px;
}

.menu-btn {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  display: block;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
}

.menu-block {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column-reverse;
}

.menu-nav {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  transition: .5s;
  transform-origin: top center;
  transform: scaleY(0) translateY(-20px);
  opacity: 0;
}
.menu-nav.with-border {
  background-color: #fff;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  padding-top: 30px;
  margin-top: -40px;
  border-radius: 50px;
}
.menu-nav--open {
  transform: scaleY(1) translateY(0);
  opacity: 1;
}
.menu-nav__name {
  position: absolute;
  right: 45px;
  top: 0;
  margin: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: .3s;
}
.menu-nav__name img {
  idth: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
.menu-nav__link {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #000;
  margin-top: 5px;
  transition: .4s;
  position: relative;
}

.menu-nav__img {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  padding-top: 20%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="section">
  <div class="menu-btn__wrapper">
    <div class="menu-block">
      <nav class="menu-nav with-border"><a class="menu-nav__link" href="#">
          <p class="menu-nav__name"></p></a><a class="menu-nav__link" href="#">
          <p class="menu-nav__name"></p><img class="menu-nav__img menu-img" src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/world-flags-1-1/100/Britain-512.png"></a><a class="menu-nav__link" href="#">
          <p class="menu-nav__name"></p><img class="menu-nav__img menu-img" src="http://icons.veryicon.com/png/Flag/Rounded%20World%20Flags/Russia%20Flag.png"></a><a class="menu-nav__link" href="#">
          <p class="menu-nav__name"></p><img class="menu-nav__img menu-img" src="https://cdn.countryflags.com/thumbs/germany/flag-round-250.png"> </a></nav><a class="menu-btn" href="#"><img class="menu-nav__img" id="main-btn-img" src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/world-flags-1-1/100/Britain-512.png"><span class="menu-btn__line"></span></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add onclick event on each menu item and replace the src of the main image with the clicked one.

```js
$(document).on('click', function (e) {
    if ($(e.target).closest(".menu-btn").length === 0) {
        $('.menu-nav').removeClass('menu-nav--open');
    }
});

$('.menu-btn').on('click', function(e){
 e.preventDefault();
 $(this).toggleClass('menu-btn--open');
 $('.menu-nav').toggleClass('menu-nav--open');
});

$('.menu-nav__link').on('click', function(e){
  $("#main-btn-img").attr('src', $(this).find('img').attr('src'));
});
```

```css
body, html {
  margin: 0;
}

.section {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background: linear-gradient(#55efc4, #ffeaa7);
  position: relative;
}

.menu-btn__wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  right: 20px;
}

.menu-btn {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  display: block;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
}

.menu-block {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column-reverse;
}

.menu-nav {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  transition: .5s;
  transform-origin: top center;
  transform: scaleY(0) translateY(-20px);
  opacity: 0;
}
.menu-nav.with-border {
  background-color: #fff;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  padding-top: 30px;
  margin-top: -40px;
  border-radius: 50px;
}
.menu-nav--open {
  transform: scaleY(1) translateY(0);
  opacity: 1;
}
.menu-nav__name {
  position: absolute;
  right: 45px;
  top: 0;
  margin: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: .3s;
}
.menu-nav__name img {
  idth: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
.menu-nav__link {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #000;
  margin-top: 5px;
  transition: .4s;
  position: relative;
}

.menu-nav__img {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  padding-top: 20%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="section">
  <div class="menu-btn__wrapper">
    <div class="menu-block">
      <nav class="menu-nav with-border"><a class="menu-nav__link" href="#">
          <p class="menu-nav__name"></p></a><a class="menu-nav__link" href="#">
          <p class="menu-nav__name"></p><img class="menu-nav__img menu-img" src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/world-flags-1-1/100/Britain-512.png"></a><a class="menu-nav__link" href="#">
          <p class="menu-nav__name"></p><img class="menu-nav__img menu-img" src="http://icons.veryicon.com/png/Flag/Rounded%20World%20Flags/Russia%20Flag.png"></a><a class="menu-nav__link" href="#">
          <p class="menu-nav__name"></p><img class="menu-nav__img menu-img" src="https://cdn.countryflags.com/thumbs/germany/flag-round-250.png"> </a></nav><a class="menu-btn" href="#"><img class="menu-nav__img" id="main-btn-img" src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/world-flags-1-1/100/Britain-512.png"><span class="menu-btn__line"></span></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```